# Publicar site ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4

Fiz o meu primeiro "site" teste em `ASP.Net` e quando vou publicar ele no meu ftp normal (estou usando visual studio 2013) eu abro o domínio http://aizensecurity.freevar.com/ fica com todas essas pastas e tal...

Como faço pra publicar ele? O que eu tenho que fazer?

Comment: Bruno, antes de mais nada, bem-vindo ao SOpt. Não esqueça de fazer o tour ver como funciona o site. Sobre a tua questão, tu instalaste o IIS no teu servidor web? Me parece que tu não tens ele instalado.

Answer (score 3):

[O Freevar não suporta ASP.NET MVC](http://www.freewebhostingarea.com/). Não vai funcionar.

[O Somee suporta](https://somee.com/default.aspx).

A maneira correta de publicar um site em ASP.NET MVC é utilizando *Web Deploy*. Não vale a pena descrever o passo-a-passo aqui. [Há vários tutoriais que podem ser usados para configurar o *Web Deploy* para seu site](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment).

Precisando de ajuda para publicar, você pode fazer uma pergunta mais específica.